# Algoritmo de inserción

Tags: c, algoritmos, ordenamiento

¿Cómo harían para que me ordene por nombre?

```
#include<Stdio.h>
#include<Stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct empleados{
    char nombre[10];
};
void insercion(struct empleados x[10],int n){
    int i,k,c;
    char aux[10];
    i=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        strcpy(aux, x[i].nombre);
        k=i-1;
        while(k>=0 && strcmp(aux,x[k].nombre) < 0){
        strcpy(x[k+1].nombre,x[k].nombre);
        k--;}
        strcpy(x[k+1].nombre,aux);
    }
}
main(){
    struct empleados emp[10];
    int i,n=4,x;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    puts("ingrese nombre");
    gets(emp[i].nombre);}
    insercion(emp,n);
    for(x=0;x<n;x++)
    printf("%d - ",emp[x].nombre);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes 2 opciones:

- Ordenar los nombres según se van introduciendo.
- Ordenar los nombres después de introducirlos todos.

En ambos casos, necesitas una función para comparar los nombres, del tipo

```
int compara( struct empleados *e1, struct empleados *e2 );
```

Esta función ha de devolver lo siguiente:

```
Si e1 va ANTES de e2, < 0
Si e1 es IGUAL que e2, 0
Si e1 va DESPUÉS DE e2, > 0
```

Échale un ojo a la función

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu función de inserción debería ser algo así:

```
#define MAX_EMPLEADOS 10
#define MAX_NOMBRE 10

void insercion(struct empleados x[MAX_EMPLEADOS], char nombre[MAX_NOMBRE])
{
    int i = 0;

    while ((strncmp(x[i].nombre, nombre, 10) > 0) && (i < MAX_EMPLEADOS))
        ++i;

    int size = sizeof(struct empleados) * (MAX_EMPLEADOS - i - 1);

    memmove(&x[i + 1], &x[i], size);
    memcpy(x[i].nombre, nombre, MAX_NOMBRE);
}
```

No me queda claro qué hacías en tu algoritmo en `insercion` pero creo que en realidad deberías recibir el arreglo en el que insertar los datos así como el dato a insertar; sin embargo tú le estás pasando el arreglo en el que insertar y un número que usabas como límite del bucle.

El algoritmo que propongo yo busca la posición en que insertar el empleado y acto seguido desplaza a la derecha el resto de empleados (perdiendo el último) lo cuál deja un hueco para el nuevo empleado, supongamos estos datos:

> empleado 0: Aaron
>
> empleado 1: Cain
>
> empleado 2: Daniel
>
> empleado 3: Ezequiel
>
> empleado 4: Faramir
>
> empleado 5: Gimli
>
> empleado 6: Hector
>
> empleado 7: Io
>
> empleado 8: Javier
>
> empleado 9: Kevin

Si queremos insertar a un empleado llamado Belcebu:

```
1) Buscar punto de inserción
|empleado 0|empleado 1|empleado 2| ... | empleado 9|
|  Aaron   |   Cain   |  Daniel  | ... |   Kevin   |
           ^
  Belcebu va entre Aaron y Cain
```

```
2) Desplazar empleados a la derecha con memmove
|empleado 0|empleado 1|empleado 2| ... | empleado 9|
|  Aaron   |   Cain   |   Cain   | ... |   Javier  |
```

```
3) Copiar el registro en el punto localizado
|empleado 0|empleado 1|empleado 2| ... | empleado 9|
|  Aaron   |  Belcebu |   Cain   | ... |   Javier  |
```